# WYSIWYG removes HTML button all non-<p> tags when view source

Tags: redactor, richtext, wysiwyg

Any code that I previously inserted using the html button on the rich text wysiwyg is removed when I click into edit the html within a post. Only `<p>` tags remain.

I have turned off the "Clean html" and the "Purify html" in the settings for the body field (rich text field), and have tried to enter iframes (videos).  I can insert them initially, but if I go back to the edit as rich text, and then click to edit the html, any iframes, divs or tags other than `<p>` tags are stripped out of the code.

I cannot edit html in any posts that have videos else the videos are stripped out.

I have also downloaded a fresh install of Craft to make sure that it wasn't just my install.  I encountered the same issue.

Can someone tell me what is going on?

Comment: Same thing happens for me... I'll have my text and I put in an image, then edit it, and it disappears. When I click the code button this is what shows up- `<p><span id="redactor-image-box" data-redactor="verified" contenteditable="false" style="float: left;"></span>
</p>`

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature of "redactor" which is used with Craft to clean and format input.

To change the settings, you need to change the config in Craft/config/redactor/. See http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/rich-text-fields and http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/clean/#setting-allowedTags

This is not, however, working for me with iframes, which is a whole other issue.

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience, this is the type of thing that occurs when PHP/HTML set-up has a bug.

You could be having an issue using the Rich Text input for entering HTML for that reason.

Perhaps you could try making the edit in your website templates/css directly.

You can find tutorials to help you on http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/introduction